# Best way to store UInt32 in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, casting, types

I'm working on an application that uses a third-party component, and this component returns a value that is of type UInt32.

I need to store this UInt32 in a Sql Server table. I was thinking about just use a simple int column and insert the value like this:

```
int value = (int)(cs - int.MaxValue);
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best way for such task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should probably take + int.MinValue. As max is 2147483647 and min is -2147483648 for 32 bit signed integer. The zero steals one value from the positive side.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use a bigint or decimal(10,0) column and defined a check constraint to ensure it's between 0 and 4 billion.
2. Defines a CLR datatype

Comment: decimal(9,0) is wrong! You should use decimal(10,0) cause 2^32 = 4294967295 and it has 10 decimal places.

Comment: Well spotted from 8 years ago

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you store it in a bigint column.